# mod_rewrite re-encoding Query String Parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string, url-encoding

I have the following mod_rewrite rule, which strips the .html extension from requests and replaces it with a trailing /

```
# Handle requests to pages ending with .html
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} .*.html$
RewriteRule    (.*).html$ $1/ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

I have discovered that if my query param contains a space, already encoded, the redirect is being re-encoded. So if the initial request is for "/search-results.html?q=some%20string", that gets rewritten to "/search-results/?q=some%2520string"

Is there another parameter I can give to mod_rewrite to prevent this re-encoding from happening?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Please note that if you want to match a dot literal, you should have `\.` in your regex, not `.`. That is not causing the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [NE] flag to avoid duplicate encoding.